# How to write a multple Not equal AND Clause in TSQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am using tsql to write query and my where clause seems to be returning too many results. It for some reason seems to be treating my Not equal AND Clause as an OR clause.

```
SELECT * 
  FROM [dbo].TestTable 
  WHERE 
  ([SomeID] <> 0) 
  AND
  ([BlahID] <> 0)
  AND
  ([TestID] <> 0)
  AND
  ([AnotherID] <> 0)

  ORDER By ID
```

I need it to return only rows where all four columns are not equal to zero. Right now it is removing rows where any of the columns are equal to zero.

My Table:

```
ID   SomeID   BlahID   TestID   AnotherID
1     0        1        4         0    
2     0        4        4         8
3     0        0        4         0
4     0        1        4         0
5     6        1        4         3
```

What I want it to return

```
ID   SomeID   BlahID   TestID   AnotherID
1     0        1        4         0    
2     0        4        4         8
4     0        1        4         0
5     6        1        4         3
```

What it Returns

```
ID   SomeID   BlahID   TestID   AnotherID
5     6        1        4         3
```

Comment: Based purely on your sample code, this should not happen. I think we need to see the real code and an example of the return values in question.

Comment: Is the query returning more rows than you want or less?

Comment: it is returning less rows then expected

Comment: Is this your complete where clause?

Comment: yes it is my complete query

Comment: Can you show a row that is returned by the query, which you don't want it to return?

Comment: based on that, you want it to return all rows where BlahID is <> 0, it does not match up with the description of the problem!

Comment: OP read what you have written. "I need it to return only rows where all four columns are not equal to zero.". Then look at the output you desire. The opposite of what you just asked for, you want rows where ANY of the 4 values are not equal to 0.

Answer (score 2):

> It keeps not returning any row that has a zero in any of these columns
>   not all of these columns

That's exactly what your query is all about. It returns rows, with no `0` at any column you've listed.

That's because if any of `AND` parts is evaluated as `false` entire condition is `false` as well. So if e.g. `TestID = 0`, the entire `WHERE` clause is `false` and the row is not being returned.

To get rows where at lease one of these columns has non-zero value, use `OR`.

Comment: OP says his query is returning too many results, and appears to be treating the `AND` as an `OR`, not sure how your answer addresses that...

Comment: @EkoostikMartin In all fairness, OP's original question was completely ambiguous. "It keeps NOT returning any row that has a zero in any of these columns [not all of the columns]"

Comment: Well after he edited to add example, it appears you did answer it correctly, not sure how the heck you figured out what he was asking consider his statements at the beginning contradicted what he said at the end of his question.....

Comment: @EkoostikMartin I've based my answer on the first version of his last sentance. It's quoted at the top of the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Easier to read (for me, at least)

Records that never have and id = 0

```
SELECT * 
  FROM [dbo].TestTable 
  WHERE 0 NOT IN ([SomeID],[BlahID],[TestID],[AnotherID])
```

Records that have at least one id <> 0

```
SELECT * FROM TestTable
WHERE EXISTS (
  SELECT 1
  FROM (VALUES(SomeID),(BlahID),(TestID),(AnotherID)) t(id)
  WHERE id <> 0
)
```

Answer (score 0):

> I need it to return only rows where all four columns are not equal to
>   zero. Right now it is removing rows where any of the columns are equal
>   to zero.

Based on your wording and revised update, what you do want is to use `OR` instead of `AND`. Not sure if the link will work, but [you can check out this SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/14446/2).

Comment: But what you just quoted says the opposite of that. Of course you are right, because his expected output clearly shows he is phrasing what he wants in completely the wrong way.

Comment: Yeah, I figured he might have wanted OR but I was waiting for clarification.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
SELECT * FROM [dbo].TestTable WHERE [BlahID] <> 0
```

The problem isn't your query, it's the results you expect.  Every row in the table has a non-zero value in at least one column, so the query returns the whole table.